# start a system service using cron - SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to override default tmp.conf at `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/` with `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` and run the cron job at midnight on everyday. The service need to run as `systemd-tmpfiles --clean`. How can I run the service at midnight, Somebody help me please?

**Sample code:**

```
tmp.conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
    - source: salt://tmp/files/tmp.conf
    - user: root
    - mode: 644
    - require:
      - user: root


run_systemd-tmpfiles:
      cron.present:
        - user: root
        - minute: 0
        - hour: 0
        - require:
          - file: tmp.conf
enable_tmp_service:
      service.running:
          - name: systemd-tmpfiles --clean
          - enable: True
          - require:
            - cron: run_systemd-tmpfiles
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the command to run as part of a cron, you would need to have that `cron.present` setup to run the command.

```
cron_systemd-tmpfiles:
  cron.present:
    - name: systemd-tmpfiles --clean
    - user: root
    - minute: 0
    - hour: 0
    - require:
      - file: tmp.conf
```

If you then want to run it in this state, you can't use the tmpfile.service, you would just run the command through a `cmd.run`, or if you only want it run when the file.managed changes, you would use `cmd.wait`

```
run tmpfiles:
  cmd.wait:
      - name: systemd-tmpfiles --clean
      - listen:
        - file: tmp.conf
```

But systemd-tmpfiles.service is already run on boot if you are using systemd, so there is no reason to enable it again.  And when it runs during the beginning of the boot process, it will run the same way tmpfile --clean runs.